# Variable length of function argument list in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to define function with argument list of variable length?

I know I can write just:

```
function() -> function([]).
function(X) when not is_list(X) -> function([X]);
function(X) -> do_something_with_arguments(X).
```

But I want to avoid this technique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it is to pass all arguments in a list:

`function(ListOfParameters)`

and then you can iterate over the said `ListOfParameters`. This way, you can have your function declaration be able to accept any number of "parameters", just add more terms to the declaration... but I am not sure that's what you were hoping.  Are you thinking along the lines of a C `vararg` parameter list?  In the positive case, read the next paragraph.

You have to remember that Erlang is based on pattern matching.  The arguments in the function "declaration" serve as matching pattern when a function is invoked.  You'll have to **leave aside your "procedural programming" mindset** in order to fully harness Erlang's power.

Comment: First part of Your answer is the same as technique as I mentioned, I thought about something similar to C so I read second part so now I have to fall back to my first solution. Thanks for response!

Comment: My pleasure!  Have fun with Erlang!

Comment: What would be best to do this, if you wanted a variable list of arguments, and then you would have to execute another function while passing the variable list of arguments to this other function?

Answer (score 9):

To be much more explicit than @jldupont: No!

It is not that it has just not been implemented, but in Erlang functions with the same name but different number of arguments are considered to be different functions so it cannot be added.

Comment: Is there a way to break up a list of arguments and apply each argument to a function?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You mean apply the same function to each element? For that use: `lists:map` or list comprehensions to get back a list of results; or `lists:foldl` to fold the return values into the call to the next element in the list.

Comment: Actually if given a list of arguments, I want to call another function and pass the list as the set of arguments. In Elixir, there's `apply`.

Comment: In erlang there is of course an `apply/3`, which is used by the elixir `apply` to do the work. Elixir is built on top of erlang, the erlang libraries and OTP.